# how to install xlibs-dev on Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid)?

Tags: c, linux, build, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to install [`V4L2`](http://alumnos.elo.utfsm.cl/~yanez/video-for-linux-2-sample-programs/) on `Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid)` that require the `xlibs-dev`installed. I tried: `sudo apt-get install xlibs-dev` but it returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xlibs-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package xlibs-dev has no installation candidate
```

then I tried:

First attempt: attemp:`sudo apt-get install xorg-dev`;

Second attemp: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`;

All failed. same install xorg-dev,updated and upgraded my packages, can't to install the xlibs-dev library. how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command

```
 apt-cache search xlib dev
```

suggest you to

```
 aptitude install libx11-dev
```

And your distribution might have V4L2. Consider installing the `v4l2ucp` package...

PS. There is no *s* letter in `xlib` because it is one library, not several!